# Cloudera cannot restart hive

Tags: hive, cloudera

I am disappointed with Cloudera - the product and the support forum, so I chose to post my question here.

For unknown reason (could be because of insufficient disk space), my cloudera vm seems hanging after one day working, so I attempted to restart it, but it throws me the following error, it would be appreciated if you can share me any light to sort it out:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason is lack of memory.  Based on the error message, you timed out.  When you are using almost all your memory any requests for new memory can take a long time because Linux has to either swap idle processes out or you have to wait for existing processes to exit to free up enough memory to meet your memory request.